# performance tips for android native app using sqlite

Tags: android, ios, performance, sqlite, scalability

We are building an application which requires good amount of data exchanges between different users. We are using SQLite to store the info and Rest api to exchange data with server.

To ensure high performance and less CPU /memory hogging but to also maintain good user experience we need following suggestions:

1 We tried running sync at frequency of 30 seconds but it hogs resources.Is there any client side framework which can be used to sync sqlite with MySQL or we have to only plan all possible events for same

2 How does applications like Gmail /twitter work- do they sync only on demand or keep on syncing in background. I feel it is on demand but not sure.

3 Notifications should be server side or client side (based on updates in sqlite). In whatsapp I observed it is client side only. If I do not click a received message I keep on getting the notification about same

4 IF we keep notifications server side and sync on demand basis. then on clicking a new notification when app will open up at that time should we make a sync call

Need an expert opinion that such applications should be designed to manage sync and notifications in such a way that it does not hogs resources and also gives online kind of experience to customer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, but I'll at least give you a direction to start.

I've run local databases in iOS and Android that are over 100 MB without incident. SQLite should never be your problem, if you use it correctly. Even with 100,000 rows of data, it is fast and efficient. Where people get into trouble is by not properly indexing the data or over-normalizing the data. A quick search can tell you how to use indexes to optimize your queries, so I won't go into that any further. Over-normalization seems to be not fully understood, so I'll go into a bit more depth on it.

When designing a server database, it is important to minimize the amount of duplicate data. This often is done by breaking up a single record into multiple tables and using foreign keys. On a 1 GB database, this type of data normalization may save 20%, which is fairly significant. This gain in storage comes at the cost of perform. Sequential lookups and joins are frequently necessary to get complete data. On a server, there are plenty of CPU cycles and memory, and no one really notices if a request takes an extra millisecond or two.

A mobile app is not a full database server. The user is actively staring at the screen waiting for the app to respond. Additionally, the CPU and memory available are minimal, which makes that delay take even longer. To add insult to injury, mobile databases are only a small portion the size of a server database and duplicate data is already pretty minimal. The same data normalization that may have saved 200 MB (20% of 1 GB) server size, may now only save 5% of 10 MB, or 500 KB. That minor gain is not worth the effort or performance hit.

When you sync, you do not need a full data set each time. You only need to get data that has changed since the last sync. In many cases, that will be no change at all. You should find a way to identify what the device has on it now and only get the changes.

It is important that the UI does not stall waiting for the network request. All network activity should be done on a background thread and notify the UI to refresh once the sync completes.

Lastly, I'll mention that SQLite is *NOT* thread safe. It is important to limit concurrency with your database access.